# What logarithmic function could produce this plot?

Tags: calculus

In a book about psychology I found this plot. It is a rough plot. It should be a logarithmic fuction, but it is also valid for negative values and it goes through the origin.

What logarithmic function could produce such plot (if possible at all?)

I mean to find a function that behaves logarithmically towards infinity and that includes the use of $log$.

[image]

Comment: xlogx doesn´t have a vertical asymtote. I mean to find a function that behaves logarithmically towards infinity.

Comment: I see. Your question should reflect what you are asking for.

Comment: The [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) looks like what you drew (though it approaches horizontal asymptotes).  If you want something else you should specify (in your post).

Comment: It should not approach a horizontal assymptote, but rather behave like a logaritmic function far away from $0$

Comment: $\operatorname{sgn}(x) \cdot \lambda \log\left(1 + \mu |x|\right)$ could look like that.

Comment: Then multiply the sigmoid function by $\log(1+|x|)$, or something.

Comment: Weight the logistic function by $\log (e+|x|)$ or something like that.

Comment: If it should behave logarithmically towards infinity, you can use $\mathrm{arsinh}(x).$